# Role problem of PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a role named `cp` with some defined privileges, then we will create some other roles which will be granted with cp role. I know Oracle can do this job. For examle `grant resources to user_name;` which means grant resources role to a user. I do the follwing test in PostgreSQL, but it does not work. Any body know this?

```
--create role cp and grant privilege
postgres=# create role cp login nosuperuser nocreatedb nocreaterole
           noinherit encrypted password 'cp';
CREATE ROLE

postgres=# grant connect on database skytf to cp;
GRANT

postgres=# \c skytf skytf;
You are now connected to database "skytf" as user "skytf".

skytf=> grant usage on schema skytf to cp;
GRANT

skytf=> grant  select on skytf.test_1 to cp;
GRANT


--create role cp_1, and grant cp role privilege to cp_1
skytf=> \c postgres postgres
You are now connected to database "postgres" as user "postgres".

postgres=# create role cp_1 login nosuperuser nocreatedb nocreaterole
           noinherit encrypted password 'cp_1';
CREATE ROLE

skytf=# grant cp to cp_1;
GRANT ROLE


--test cp_1
skytf=# \c skytf cp_1;
You are now connected to database "skytf" as user "cp_1".

skytf=> select * from skytf.test_1 limit 1;
ERROR:  permission denied for schema skytf
LINE 1: select * from skytf.test_1 limit 1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are explicitly setting the role to `noinherit` so you will need to use [`set role`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-set-role.html)`cp` before your `select` to use the permissions from role `cp` (but I'm guessing you probably just want to `inherit`)

From the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createrole.html):

> INHERIT
>   NOINHERIT
>
> These clauses determine whether a role "inherits"
>   the privileges of roles it is a member of. A role with the INHERIT
>   attribute can automatically use whatever database privileges have been
>   granted to all roles it is directly or indirectly a member of. Without
>   INHERIT, membership in another role only grants the ability to SET
>   ROLE to that other role; the privileges of the other role are only
>   available after having done so. If not specified, INHERIT is the
>   default.

Comment: ach! Ya beat me! :D

Answer (score 4):

You're specifically asking pg to NOT apply the roles of 'cp' to user 'cp_1'.

> INHERIT
>   NOINHERIT
>   These clauses determine whether a role "inherits"
>   the privileges of roles it is a member of. A role with the INHERIT
>   attribute can automatically use whatever database privileges have been
>   granted to all roles it is directly or indirectly a member of. Without
>   INHERIT, membership in another role only grants the ability to SET
>   ROLE to that other role; the privileges of the other role are only
>   available after having done so. If not specified, INHERIT is the
>   default.

Try something like this:

`create role cp_1 login nosuperuser nocreatedb nocreaterole inherit encrypted password 'cp_1' in role cp`

Comment: I'd call that a tie :)

Comment: thank you very much , both the answer is right , but I just can choose a one